# Am I allowed to offer a cash bounty?

Tags: support

To workaround that fact I have insufficient rep for [How can I start a bounty for this Question?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12630/how-can-i-start-a-bounty-for-this-question) .

Comment: You could offer a cash bounty but the question would be closed.  Monetary rewards for answering a question are not allowed here at SE.  The best way to insure an answer to your question is submitted is to improve your question.  If you are not getting answers then it is very likely there isn't enough information to answer it.  It also is possible we simply do not know the answer to the question.

Comment: "The best way to insure an answer to your question is submitted is to improve your question." How? The question is as simple as stated -- How may I get Explorer to preview .m3u files as text? -- and I have already included the two failed solutions.

Comment: You have tried whats described in the answer with the awarded bounty so Update your question.  You have several grammatical issues in your question so fix those.  You mention a question, so quote and specifically specify what you tried from that question.  These are just three of the things you could do to improve the quality of your question I got like 10 more

Comment: "You have several grammatical issues in your question so fix those." None seen. "You mention a question, so quote and specifically specify what you tried from that question" Already done. "These are just three of the things you could do to improve" Sorry, but "Update your question" doesn't count. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ChrissJJ - You have not updated your question, to reflect the answer you awarded a bounty too, did not work.  You did not quote, what you actually tried, just linked to the question.  I am attempting to help you improve your question to draw attention to it, without, actually awarding a bounty.  By doing so, and when you have enough reputation, you increase your chances of getting an answer by improving it.  You could also just sit back and do nothing to improve your question.  **How about this, do all of that, and I will offer a bounty myself.**

Comment: Answer now found and posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your generosity is appreciated, but I must inform you that the ability to offer actual money as a bounty is not currently implemented. Judging by [the feature request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615/295684) (and [a duplicate thereof](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243404/295684) and [a similar one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57850/295684)), it will likely not be added. The reasoning given for that decision was that introducing real cash as reward would exacerbate the (usually) friendly and constructive competition we currently have into unhealthy money seeking. Additionally, it would likely demotivate the many answering users who give of their knowledge freely, thereby taking expert attention away from the question authors who do not have real money to spend.

If you would like to promote your question further using the bounty system, the best way would be to earn the necessary reputation by contributing answers. Once you get over 200, you'll be able to place a bounty on that question again. In the meantime, if you run across any new relevant information or try any new approaches, make sure to edit that into your post; it might help a potential answer writer. Editing has the added bonus of bumping the question to the front page. While tiny edits intended only to bump are frowned upon, the improvement of a question is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks. I rarely see questions that I can answer. It would be nice if superuser gave more support for question such as this.

Comment: @ChrisJJ So find a question you think you can answer, research the question, then submit a quality answer.  Which is basically all I have ever done in the majority of my 500+ answers